# Volume of a Solid of Revolution Rotated Around the Y-Axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Sorry to post an obvious homework question here, but my daughter's calculus teacher isn't much on "teaching" and left a problem like this one out of the notes.  I can't find much on the internet to deal with our exact problem (or I don't know how to make the connection).  Here is the problem:

Find the volume of a solid of revolution generated by revolving the region bounded by $y=x, y=0$, and $2 \le x \le 4$ about the $y$-axis.

We also then have to rotate it around the line $x=4$.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.  I found the Khan Academy tutorials on the methods helpful, but didn't know how to apply them over the specified range instead of rotating the entire graph.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Y Axis, we would want to use the shell method. The graph of the area you want to revolve can be seen [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/alww6xiulc). The shell method states that the volume of revolution is equal to

$$2\pi\int^4_2xf(x)$$

We know f(x) = x, so we have

$$2\pi\int^4_2x^2$$

Comment: Thank you.  I understand this answer and when I solve that out, I do get the correct answer of 117.286.  How do I rotate that around $x=4$, then?  I tried assuming that since $f(x) = x$, I could do $f(x) = 4$ and get

$$
2\pi \int_2^4 4x
$$

But, that does not get the correct answer of 33.510 when I work it out.

Comment: You just increment the radius so it is correct at the starting and ending points. (so instead of a radius of x, you would a radius of (4-x)